# Why is there such wide variation in the appearance of the hybrids?

Tags: sweet-tooth

On the show *Sweet Tooth*, some of the hybrids (like Wendy and Gus) are mostly human in appearance, with a handful of external animalistic features (e.g. deer horns and ears), whereas others, like Bobby, have much less human features, almost resembling anthropomorphic animals. This is in addition to the variety of animals that their features seem to come from.

The implication in the show seems to be that the same virus that was used to

> create Gus

is responsible for all the children being born with animal features (somehow...) so it is surprising that there is such drastic individual variation.

Is there any reason for this, or is it simply random?

Comment: I don't know how faithful the show is to the comics but are you open from answers from there as well? (Side meta note: does this need the [[tag:dc]] tag?)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - Sure. It does not need the DC tag, if it is not from the comics, since the show is from WB.

Comment: Not putting it as an answer since it's just my impression, but I got the feeling that the hybridization is somewhat progressive... not in the sense that kids become more hybridy, but rather that the whatever's causing people to give birth to hybrids is getting more intense and thus, that kids born later tend to be MORE animal-like. (Though it could also be a practical matter where kids who are younger are easier to replace with animatronics than having them to sit still through extensive makeup and prosthetics)